# Having trouble with git implementation

Tags: git, xampp

I'm having problem implementing version control or git to be exact on my localhost. we have a project to be done and we need to edit this project simultaneously the project folder is located in xampp/htdocs/project. what i need is to make the project folder our git server clone it thru our laptop and update each revisions we did. But all i manage to do right now is install git on local server computer. Can anyone guide me with this thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to your project and execute git init.  This creates a .git subdirectory in the project root, which contains all of the necessary metadata for the repo.

To clone on another machine, you need to:

```
$ cd /path/to/webroot/directory
$ git clone /path/to/git-repo
```

Comment: after that all i need to do is to clone the project folder with .git to another terminal?